# Express.js separate model, view and controller

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am fairly new to using Express.js but, have written a few apps.  I always end-up connecting to the database in my app.js file and appending the db connection to every request object, as follows:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk  = require('monk');
var db    = monk('localhost:27017/db');

app.use( function(req,res,next) {
    req.db = db;
    next();
});
```

Then, inside of my route files I would do the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {

    var db = req.db;
    var person = db.get('person');

    person.find( {}, {}, function(err, docs) {
        if ( err ) { console.log("error"); }

        res.status(200);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
        res.end();
    });
});
```

However, I am going through an old application that I created an I want to separate the model from my route files.  For example, continuing with the above example I would like to be able to do something like:

```
var person = require('./person-model');

router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {
    var list = person.get();

    res.status(200);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(list);
    res.end();
});
```

What is the best way to execute this approach?  Should I return a promise from the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull out all the model parts of the file, and put them into a new one wherever it makes sense in your project structure. Then, whatever methods you need to use, you can put on an object that you use in conjunction with [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports). For example, if you just want the `db` to be exported, you can simply set `module.exports` to the `db` object.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk  = require('monk');
var db    = monk('localhost:27017/db');

module.exports = db;
```

Then, in your routes file, you can do something like this:

```
var person = require("./models/person-model.js");

router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {
    var list = person.get();

    res.status(200);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(list);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Ok.  However, in the file person-model.js let's assume I implement a get() function.  Would I return the promise ?  Or the array of results ?  For example, would I return person.find({},{}); Or would process the promise in the model and return the results person.find({},{}).then() { .. return [array of results] }

Comment: That's really up to you in how you want to implement it. If it's an asynchronous operation, it'd probably best to return the promise, particularly because returning an array from a consumed promise does not block execution until it finishes.